# Получение всего содержимого таблицы

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Почему здесь выбирается только одна строка таблицы? А мне нужно все содержимое таблицы `mail`.

```
     <?php
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail ");
       $r = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
      ?>

  <table>
     <tr>
        <td>Имя</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Сообщение</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['messages']; ?></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail ");
  $r = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
     $r[] = $row;
  }
?>
```

теперь у вас в массиве $r находятся все строки

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <td>Имя</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Сообщение</td>
     </tr>
     <?php foreach($r as $row) : ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['messages']; ?></td>
        </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
  </table>
```